# Spring Integration multiple FTP hosts (DefaultFtpSessionFactory)

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I would like to know whether it is possible to configure multiple hosts in one instance of DefaultFtpSessionFactory / DefaultSftpSessionFactory .

The previous code what I had used to send a generated file to a FTP location. Now it is required that the same copy of the generated file must be sent to two FTP locations.

One of the possibility is that to send the file to a PUB-SUB channel and to have two outbound adapters sending to two different locations.
*I do not prefer this because if the file has to be sent to three locations in future then similar changes have to be done.*

Another possibility would be that the remote location details is to be enriched in header and the corresponding details have to be taken out when locating the FTP in the outbound adapter. 
*I have this approach under consideration but I do not know whether it'd work or not.*

Does Spring provide some host resolver where I can provide the hosts or the ports to the DefaultFtpSessionFactory, each one is seperated by a delimiter (*say ; or so. Like **192.168.2.1;192.168.2.4***)?

Is there any other approach to this problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Each default session factory can only connect to one server. There are several solutions; see the [dynamic ftp sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/advanced/dynamic-ftp) and the [Delegating Session Factory](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ftp.html#ftp-dsf).